# How does c# handle the memory for static members

Tags: c#, memory-management, static-methods, static-classes

Made a lot of searches but none ended up clarifying my doubt.

When one use a static class or method, when does c# allocates memory for them? And does it get deallocated at all?

Bonus question: When should one use a static member or class?

Comment: On the first use of that class. It doesn't get deallocated.

Comment: On the bonus question: Use a static member or class whenever you need one.

Comment: It allocates memory at compile-time, most likely. But this is really an implementation detail, not something you need to worry about. What problem are you trying to solve? Why does this matter?

Comment: @CodyGray You cannot allocate memory for a program when compiling that program...

Comment: Of course you can, @servy. The information is placed in the static data area of the binary image (.data/.bss sections). That allocation happens at compile time. The compiler with the cooperation of the linker allocates space for that data and knows what its address is. I don't know if you're trying to make the point that the binary image has to be mapped into memory when it is loaded, so it is actually the loader that performs the allocation? While that's certainly a valid perspective, it would then be true that the runtime doesn't allocate dynamic memory, either: the OS VMM does.

Comment: @CodyGray Your arguing that the compiler is defining *what the memory will be initialized to, when it is allocated*, which is of course correct.  That's very different from saying the compiler allocates the memory.

Comment: It allocates space for the memory...in memory (since this particular section of the binary image gets loaded into the process's memory space by the OS's loader). It doesn't necessarily determine what the memory will be initialized to. The program can still do that at run-time, assuming it's not in a read-only segment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

> As is the case with all class types, the type information for a static class is loaded by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) when the program that references the class is loaded. The program cannot specify exactly when the class is loaded. However, it is guaranteed to be loaded and to have its fields initialized and its static constructor called before the class is referenced for the first time in your program. A static constructor is only called one time, and a static class remains in memory for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program resides.

Answer (score 4):

> When one use a static class or method, when does c# allocates memory for them?

It's not C# who allocates memory, it's the underlying CLR. You also should differentiate *allocation* of memory and actual *initialization* of members.

The *allocation* of memory can happen when the program (EXE, DLL) is loaded into the memory. This is because in a “typical” implementation static data memebers are allocated on the so called `data` segment. That's a fixed portion of memory dedicated to hold permanent (from the run-time perspective) data structures. However, a specific implementation may work a bit differently, even though will have to be some sort of a static `data` segment, at least holding pointers to other data structures.

The *initialization* happens before the class is first accessed.

> And does it get deallocated at all?

No. They are static.

---

> Bonus question: When should one use a static member or class?

*Side note: This is not a bonus question, but rather a reason for closing a question as primarily opinion based.*

Comment: Thank you Ondrej! Helped me a lot.